# How to replace the checkbox from the UI Fabric DetailsList component

Tags: office-ui-fabric

How can I replace the circle checkbox of a DetailsList in office-ui-fabric-react with a normal square CheckBox component? I see onRenderCheckbox so I try something like this:

```
onRenderCheckbox={(props) => (<Checkbox checked={props.checked} />)}
```

or

```
onRenderCheckbox={(props) => (<Checkbox {...props} />)}
```

I can see the square checkbox but I can't select it.
What it the proper way to do this?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you render the `Checkbox` component, it handles the click itself (and thus it won't percolate up to the row so it can toggle selection accordingly), so you need to prevent it with the `pointer-events: none` style.

```
onRenderCheckbox(props) {
    return (
        <div style={{ pointerEvents: 'none' }}>
            <Checkbox checked={props.checked} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Check it out here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zQXEPr

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works! It makes, yet, I would have never found that out.

Comment: Man it would be so nice if details like this were actually documented!